# What are customization point objects and how to use them?

Tags: c++, c++20

The last draft of the c++ standard introduces the so-called "customization point objects" ([[customization.point.object]](http://eel.is/c++draft/customization.point.object)),
which are widely used by the ranges library.

I seem to understand that they provide a way to write custom version of `begin`, `swap`, `data`, and the like, which are
found by the standard library by ADL. Is that correct?

How is this different from previous practice where a user defines an overload for e.g. `begin` for her type in her own
namespace? In particular, why are they *objects*?

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4381.html

Answer (score 57, accepted):

> What are customization point objects?

They are function object instances in namespace `std` that fulfill two objectives: *first* unconditionally trigger (conceptified) type requirements on the argument(s), *then* dispatch to the correct function in namespace `std` or via ADL.

> In particular, why are they *objects*?

That's necessary to circumvent a second lookup phase that would directly bring in the user provided function via ADL (this should be *postponed* by design). See below for more details.

> ... and how to use them?

When developing an application: you mainly don't. This is a standard library feature, it will add concept checking to future customization points, hopefully resulting e.g. in clear error messages when you mess up template instantiations. However, with a qualified call to such a customization point, you can directly use it. Here's an example with an imaginary `std::customization_point` object that adheres to the design:

```
namespace a {
    struct A {};
    // Knows what to do with the argument, but doesn't check type requirements:
    void customization_point(const A&);
}

// Does concept checking, then calls a::customization_point via ADL:
std::customization_point(a::A{});
```

This is currently not possible with e.g. `std::swap`, `std::begin` and the like.

### Explanation (a summary of [N4381](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4381.html))

Let me try to digest the proposal behind this section in the standard. There are two issues with "classical" customization points used by the standard library.

- They are easy to get wrong. As an example, swapping objects in generic code is supposed to look like this

  ```
  template<class T> void f(T& t1, T& t2)
  {
      using std::swap;
      swap(t1, t2);
  }
  ```

  but making a qualified call to `std::swap(t1, t2)` instead is too simple - the user-provided
  `swap` would never be called (see
  [N4381](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4381.html), Motivation and Scope)
- More severely, there is no way to centralize (conceptified) constraints on types passed to such user provided functions (this is also why this topic gained importance with C++20). Again
  from [N4381](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4381.html):

  > Suppose that a future version of `std::begin` requires that its argument model a Range concept.
  >   Adding such a constraint would have no effect on code that uses `std::begin` idiomatically:
  >   
  >   `using std::begin;`
  >   
  >   `begin(a);`
  >   
  >   If the call to begin dispatches to a user-defined overload, then the constraint on `std::begin`
  >   has been bypassed.

The solution that is described in the proposal mitigates both issues
by an approach like the following, imaginary implementation of `std::begin`.

```
namespace std {
    namespace __detail {
        /* Classical definitions of function templates "begin" for
           raw arrays and ranges... */

        struct __begin_fn {
            /* Call operator template that performs concept checking and
             * invokes begin(arg). This is the heart of the technique.
             * Everyting from above is already in the __detail scope, but
             * ADL is triggered, too. */

        };
    }

    /* Thanks to @cpplearner for pointing out that the global
       function object will be an inline variable: */
    inline constexpr __detail::__begin_fn begin{}; 
}
```

First, a qualified call to e.g. `std::begin(someObject)` always detours via `std::__detail::__begin_fn`,
which is desired. For what happens with an unqualified call, I again refer to the original paper:

> In the case that begin is called unqualified after bringing `std::begin` into scope, the situation
>     is different. In the first phase of lookup, the name begin will resolve to the global object
>     `std::begin`. Since lookup has found an object and not a function, the second phase of lookup is not
>     performed. In other words, if `std::begin` is an object, then `using std::begin; begin(a);` is
>     equivalent to `std::begin(a);` which, as we’ve already seen, does argument-dependent lookup on the
>     users’ behalf.

This way, concept checking can be performed within the function object in the `std` namespace,
*before* the ADL call to a user provided function is performed. There is no way to circumvent this.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `constexpr auto begin = __detail::__begin_fn{}` in the anonimous namespace?

Comment: Note that the ODR trickery is made moot by C++17 inline variables. Now `inline constexpr __detail::__begin_fn begin{};` should suffice.

Comment: Is it an implementation detail of the standard library or must the user take care of customization points?

Comment: @Oliv If I understand it correctly, there is no need to "take care" of customization points - except providing the appropriate overload of the function with the same name. Same as it has been for e.g. `swap`.

Comment: Re the draft by Eric Niebler. He has a great blog post about customization points here: http://ericniebler.com/2014/10/21/customization-point-design-in-c11-and-beyond/

Comment: There are no CPOs in `std::` directly, IIRC.

Comment: If we're going all out, you should also wrap the `begin` object in an inline namespace

Comment: Where [in the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/customization.point.object) do you get the requirement that a CPO must be the same across TUs? Or is that a relict from their conception with the range-ts?

Comment: @Deduplicator Not sure whether I understand what you mean, where in the answer is a reference to such a requirement?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, customization points like `std::begin` are still free functions and not function objects as for C++20 isn't? The only customization points implemented as functions objects are those from the ranges library like `std::ranges::begin`.

Comment: @Peregring-lk I think so too, otherwise this would break backward compatibility.

Comment: @lubgr Thanks. It was in doubt because `std::begin` is the most usual example used to explained customization point objects while not being actually implemented that way.

Comment: Confusing. I got to this page because I was thinking about the growing trend in the C++ standard to work with customization points that are defined by classes in general, not just those that satisfy the "Callable" concept. E.g. the Coroutines TS relies heavily on several classes to be defined. But here it was stated that CPOs are "Function Objects." I hope that's not correct because if so it would be yet another terrible nomenclature that is confusing. It seems to me that they are all CPOs, regardless of whether they have operator(). Otherwise, what do you call non-callable ones?

Answer (score 24):

"Customization point object" is a bit of a misnomer. Many - probably a majority - aren't actually customization points.

Things like `ranges::begin`, `ranges::end`, and `ranges::swap` are "true" CPOs. Calling one of those causes some complex metaprogramming to take place to figure out if there is a valid customized `begin` or `end` or `swap` to call, or if the default implementation should be used, or if the call should instead be ill-formed (in a SFINAE-friendly manner). Because a number of library concepts are defined in terms of CPO calls being valid (like `Range` and `Swappable`), correctly constrained generic code must use such CPOs. Of course, if you know the concrete type and another way to get an iterator out of it, feel free.

Things like `ranges::cbegin` are CPOs without the "CP" part. They always do the default thing, so it's not much of a customization point. Similarly, range adaptor objects are CPOs but there's nothing customizable about them. Classifying them as CPOs is more of a matter of consistency (for `cbegin`) or specification convenience (adaptors).

Finally, things like `ranges::all_of` are quasi-CPOs or *niebloids*. They are specified as function templates with special magical ADL-blocking properties and weasel wording to allow them to be implemented as function objects instead. This is primarily to prevent ADL picking up the unconstrained overload in namespace `std` when a constrained algorithm in `std::ranges` is called unqualified. Because the `std::ranges` algorithm accepts iterator-sentinel pairs, it's usually less specialized than its `std` counterpart and loses overload resolution as a result.

Comment: What about `ranges::data`, `ranges::size`, and `ranges::empty`? Are they "true" CPO?

Comment: Yes, those are actually customizable.