# Is there a nice way to assign std::minmax(a, b) to std::tie(a, b)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, reference, stl, c++17

```
std::tie(a, b) = std::minmax(a, b);
```

I think this is intuitive code. Clean and understandable. Too bad it doesn't work as intended, as [`std::minmax`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax) templates for `const&`. If therefore the values are swapped inside the `std::pair<const&, const&>` than one assignement will overwrite the other value:

```
auto[a, b] = std::make_pair(7, 5);

std::tie(a, b) = std::minmax(a, b);

std::cout << "a: " << a << ", b: " << b << '\n';
```

> a: 5, b: 5

The expected output here is `a: 5, b: 7`.

---

I think this is important as implementing transform functions to apply a function onto some ranges requires such statements for intuitive lambdas. For example:

```
std::vector<int> v{ 0, 1, 0, 2, 0 };
std::vector<int> u{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 };

perform(v.begin(), v.end(), u.begin(), [](auto& a, auto& b){ 
    std::tie(a, b) = std::minmax(a, b);    
}); 

//v would be == {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
//u would be == {1, 1, 1, 2, 1}
```

---

One solution I found was constructing an [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) explicitly without any reference qualifiers over the `std::pair<const&, const&>` to enforce a copy:

```
std::tie(a, b) = std::tuple<int, int>(std::minmax(a, b));
```

But this `<int, int>` redundancy seems rather awful, especially when having said`auto& a, auto& b` before.

---

Is there a nice, short way to perform this assignement? Could it be that this is the wrong direction and just saying `if (a >= b) { std::swap(a, b); }` would be the best approach here?

Comment: While the answers provided are nice, I'm somewhat unhappy about the temporaries, as these might get costly with some data types. So I personally would rather go with the `if-swap` approach. You might pack it in your own `minmax_inplace` template function (with void return type)...

Comment: @Aconcagua I benchmarked [100k - 10mil elements]: without optimizations: `if-swap` was **~2.0 times faster**. with optimizations: `if-swap` was **~1.5 times faster**. So if speed is required, I would certainly go for `if-swap`

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use an initializer list for `minmax`:

```
std::tie(a, b) = std::minmax({a, b});
```

This causes temporary objects to be created, just like when using *unary plus*, but has the benefit that it works with types lacking the *unary plus* operator too.

```
using namespace std::string_view_literals;

auto [a, b] = std::make_pair("foo"sv, "bar"sv);
std::tie(a, b) = std::minmax({a, b});
std::cout << "a: " << a << ", b: " << b << '\n';
```

Output:

```
a: bar, b: foo
```

> Could it be that this is the wrong direction and just saying `if (a >= b) { std::swap(a, b); }` would be the best approach here?

I'd make it `if(b < a) std::swap(a, b);` because of the [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare)<sup>1</sup> requirement, but yes, I suspect that'll be faster and it's still very clear what you want to accomplish.

---

<sup>[1] 
 <sub>Compare [...] The return value of the function call operation applied to an object
 of a type satisfying Compare, when contextually converted to bool,
 yields true if the first argument of the call appears before the
 second in the strict weak ordering relation induced by this type, and
 false otherwise.</sub></sup>

Comment: This has the nice benefit that it works for more types as well (can't unary-`+` a `std::string`, for instance).

Comment: You may want to note that this causes the creation of temporary objects so it could be expensive.

Comment: @NathanOliver Well, you need temporaries. Can't really get around that? Problem is that this does copies instead of moves because of `initializer_list`... Can't get around that either :-(

Comment: @Barry Well, if the OP is fine with a custom function doing a swap and returning a pair of references, or not even returning anything, would bypass any temporary creation.

Comment: I agree, this is the shortest, least confusing and most maintainable approach.

Comment: @TedLyngmo what's better about `b < a` than `a >= b`? Given todays optimization, does it really matter? Or is the reason readability as to indicate that the case where `a == b` is not directly adressed?

Comment: @StackDanny Yes, if the type involved in the comparison has `operator>=` it'll probably be just as effective. It's just that the usual requirement on types that should be sorted is that `operator<` should exists, so for that reason alone, I prefer sticking to that operator everywhere.

Answer (score 29):

You can enforce this with a certain level of brevity as follows.

```
std::tie(a, b) = std::minmax(+a, +b);

std::cout << "a: " << a << ", b: " << b << '\n';
```

Explanation: the builtin unary plus operator, for the sake of symmetry with its unary minus sibling, returns its operand *by value* (it also performs the usual arithmetic conversions, but that doesn't apply to `int`s). This means it has to create a temporary, even though this temporary is nothing but a copy of the operand. But for the usage of `minmax` in this example, it's sufficient: swapping references here doesn't assign through anymore, because the references on the right hand side (the `const int&` arguments passed to `minmax`) don't refer to the same objects as those on the left hand side (inside the `tuple` of references created by `std::tie`).

The output is as desired:

> a: 5, b: 7

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes, taking a step back and finding a different way pays off:

```
if (b < a)
    std::iter_swap(&a, &b);
```

That's concise and generally more efficient, certainly at least on par. Maybe pack it into its own function:

```
template <class T>
void reorder(T& a, T& b)
noexcept(noexcept(b < a, void(), std::iter_swap(&a, &b))) {
    if (b < a)
        std::iter_swap(&a, &b);
}
```

I'm using [`std::iter_swap()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap) so I don't have to use the `using std::swap; swap(a, b)` two-step for generality in pre-C++2a, which introduces [customization point objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53495848/what-are-customization-point-objects-and-how-to-use-them) making that obsolete.

Comment: Doesn't that just make `iter_swap` dereference the pointers back to do a normal `swap` on the objects, like `std::swap(*a, *b);`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo No, it uses the two-step, finding customized implementations over ADL.

Comment: @TedLyngmo It's defined in `std` (as a replacement for importing `using std::swap;`), and calls `swap()` unqualified. Voila, the two-step, adapted to implementing `std`.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. For fundamental and std types, will it be able to choose a different `swap()` implementation than `swap` itself does? I was under the impression that `swap` also did some trickery to select customized implementations over the old _copy one obj to tmp ..._-thingy.

Comment: @TedLyngmo `std::swap()` is a lot of overloads: 1. The generic algorithm for single objects. 2. The generic algorithm for native arrays. 3. Some custom implementations for types also in `std`. The two-step, calling `std::iter_swap()` instead, or C++2a CPOs are for ensuring custom implementations for user-defined types are found by ADL.

Comment: Sounds really nice. You get +1 from me for making me aware of this. Any reason to not use it over a plain `std::swap` always? Perhaps you could add some of your explanations in the answer too? It wasn't obvious what two-step meant in this context for me at least.