# Does std::(customization point) invoke the most appropriate overload?

Tags: c++, overloading, std, c++20, argument-dependent-lookup

Since C++20, the concept of *customization point* is introduced in [[namespace.std]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/namespace.std#7):

> Other than in namespace std or in a namespace within namespace std, a program may provide an overload for any library function template designated as a *customization point*, provided that (a) the overload's declaration depends on at least one user-defined type and (b) the overload meets the standard library requirements for the customization point. [ Note: This permits a (**qualified** or unqualified) call to the customization point to invoke the most appropriate overload for the given arguments. — end note ]

Does the note part (note the emphasized word "qualified") mean that `std::f` will automatically invoke the most appropriate overload for `f` if `std::f` is a customization point?

A real example is [`std::swap`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/utility.swap#1), which is a designated customization point. Does this mean since C++20, we can write `std::swap(a, b)` directly instead of [`using std::swap; swap(a, b);`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2684544/5376789)?

Comment: IANALL, but this new concept probably doesn't affect how ADL works so I would expect you still want an unqualified call.

Comment: @jtbandes Yes, ADL is still there, but there is [some trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53497055/5376789) that can make it possible for std::f to automatically invoke the most appropriate overload.

Comment: I've filed this as an issue: https://wg21.link/lwg3441

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A real example is `std::swap`, which is a designated customization point. Does this mean since C++20, we can write `std::swap(a, b)` directly instead of using `std::swap; swap(a, b);`?

No. `std::swap` itself did not gain any powers. It's still just a function template, so if you call it directly, you're... calling it directly. No ADL or anything.

The point of this is to say *how* customization points should be opted into. That is, you write:

```
namespace N { // not std
    void swap(Foo&, Foo&);
}
```

Not:

```
namespace std {
    void swap(N::Foo&, N::Foo&);
}
```

Nor:

```
namespace std {
    template <>
    void swap(N::Foo&, N::Foo&);
}
```

---

However, C++20 does introduce a lot of new things called [customization point objects](http://eel.is/c++draft/customization.point.object) which you *can* use directly do this kind of thing. The CPO for `swap` is spelled [`std::ranges::swap`](http://eel.is/c++draft/concept.swappable#lib:ranges::swap) (and likewise there are CPOs for all the useful ranges things... `ranges::begin`, `ranges::end`, etc.).

Comment: The name `std::ranges::swap` is not introduced in [ranges], how strange! So what's the meaning of the note in [namespace.std]/7 while it explicitly states "[t]his permits a (**qualified** or unqualified) call ..."?

Comment: @xskxzr `std::iter_swap(x, y)` will find your `swap` too.

Comment: "That is, you write..." I don't think so, the note is saying "(qualified or unqualified) **call**", not about declarations.

Comment: @xskxzr And the rest of the paragraph talks about declaring this not in `std` (importantly, not as a specialization).

Comment: Yes, but now I'm confused about the note part.